# 'CanMatch' is deprecated.ts(6385) index.d.ts(626, 4): The declaration was marked as deprecated here. (alias) interface CanMatch

Tags: angular, angular15

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRouteSnapshot, CanActivate, CanActivateChild, CanMatch, Route, RouterStateSnapshot, UrlSegment, UrlTree } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate, CanActivateChild, CanMatch {
  canActivate(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree {
    return true;
  }
  canActivateChild(
    childRoute: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree {
    return true;
  }
  canMatch(
    route: Route,
    segments: UrlSegment[]): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Can someone help to resolve deprecated events

Comment: The [documentation](https://angular.io/api/router/CanMatch) is quite clear about it. What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 1):

The class-based guards are deprecated in favour of functional guards so no need for the guard class any more, you can export each of those functions to be injectable classes, as written in documentation, see

```
canMatch: [() => inject(myGuard).canMatch()]
```